# Active bounties for X reputation layout bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounties

When viewing the active bounties from the user activity page, the h1 header saying "Active bounties from X reputation" is too close to the separator line below it. I'm guessing this happens when the bounty count is greater than 0, since on other sites, where I have no current bounties, the layout is fine. Below is a screenshot from [my activity on Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano?tab=bounties), where the bug is visible:

[image: Bounty separator intersection]

I'm using Iceweasel 38.2.1esr-1~deb7u1 (amd64) on Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy). I can also reproduce this with Iceweasel 38.2.1esr-1~Iceweasel deb8u1 (amd64) on Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie), although this could be due to the browser version being the same.

This question was copied from [the same one on SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264606/active-bounties-for-x-reputation-layout-bug), since my migration flag went unnoticed.

<sup>Bumping this question since the bug is still there, and is also quite ugly.</sup>

Comment: Looks like this on Firefox on MacOS as well.

Comment: @Pops I'm pinning you since this went unnoticed and you seemed to have fixed similar bugs previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed on the 19th of May 2016, as per Pops' edit on the question. Looking at the bounty page now confirms this.